# How can I increase the /tmp directory on Linux

Tags: linux, size, tmp

I am trying to install android-studio from the Arch User Repository (AUR). I had an error no space left on the device

Output from the Arch User Repository (AUR) - details

```
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  737M  100  737M    0     0  4497k      0  0:02:48  0:02:48 --:--:-- 4908k
  -> Found android-studio.desktop
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux.zip ... Passed
    android-studio.desktop ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux.zip with bsdtar
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> Starting package()...
==> Tidying install...
  -> Removing libtool files...
  -> Purging unwanted files...
  -> Removing static library files...
  -> Compressing man and info pages...
==> Checking for packaging issue...
==> Creating package "android-studio"...
  -> Generating .PKGINFO file...
  -> Generating .BUILDINFO file...
  -> Generating .MTREE file...
  -> Compressing package...
cat: write error: No space left on device
bsdtar: Write error
==> ERROR: Failed to create package file.
```

Using the Terminal

```
➜  ~ df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
run                                  3.8G  1.3M  3.8G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/AntergosVG-AntergosRoot  102G   91G  6.5G  94% /
tmpfs                                3.8G   62M  3.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                            243M  109M  118M  48% /boot
tmpfs                                3.8G  3.8G     0 100% /tmp
tmpfs                                769M   20K  769M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Now I clear some space on /tmp

```
➜  ~ df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
run                                  3.8G  1.3M  3.8G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/AntergosVG-AntergosRoot  102G   91G  6.5G  94% /
tmpfs                                3.8G   63M  3.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                            243M  109M  118M  48% /boot
tmpfs                                3.8G  8.0K  3.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                                769M   20K  769M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Then I tryied to reinstall android-studio but I still have the same error.  I don't know why that upon download a 737MB file the building takes 3.8GB.  How can I increase the size of my /tmp directory to 4.5GB?

Comment: Simple answer -- build it in / (probably /home/username) or somewhere where it has more space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remount /tmp:

```
# mount -o remount,size=4500M /tmp
```

Comment: Just know that this will consume computer's RAM, as /tmp is a tmpfs filesystem (uses RAM to emulate disk).